# AlertDialog.Builder does't work in my if statment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a game which when the bird reaches 0 life, an alert dialog pops up.
I try to put it in my "if statment" like this :

```
//Some code...

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);

                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You lost. you can do better next time! ");

                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Start Over", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Close ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();

// More code
```

but the moment I choose the name of the activity (GameActivity) -or any actually-, I get this :

[image]

I know that the Alert Dialog code is correct, but I don't get it.

Please help.

Comment: The argument inside `Builder(...)` is supposed to be `context`.

Comment: I am just a beginner. So, can you please give me an example?